# How can I display an unordered list under an image?

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I am trying to place a profile image above some details but it won't change position. I have tried to use display: block but it didn't work.

```css
.imgDetails {
 display: block;
 }

.profileimg {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 }
.profileText {
 font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5vw;
 }
```

```html
<div class="imgDetails">
        <figure class="profileimg">
            <img src="studentdata/placeholder/profile.jpg"  alt="student Profile Picture">
          </figure>                        
            <ul>
                <li class ="profileText">Name</li>
                <li class ="profileText">University</li>
                <li class ="profileText">Year</li>
            </ul>
```

[This is what I am getting now, I need to swap the image at the top and the ul at below]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image in css. i mean background-image: url("paper.gif");  and than you can display anything over the image. You can use another css property opacity to see nice.